# How is $\frac{1-x}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{x+1}$?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, indefinite-integrals, fractions

When integrating $\int \frac{1-x}{x^2-1} dx$ Maple rewrote it as $-\int\frac{1}{x+1}dx$

How is $\frac{1-x}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{x+1}$?

Comment: Have you tried factoring the denominator?

Comment: It's not, you missed a negative. And Hint: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: Very strictly speaking, those two equations are not the same. They have different domains.

Comment: very strictly speaking, those are two functions, not two equations.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang what's the difference? Aren't functions defined by equations?

Comment: @Celeritas: Very strictly speaking, Matthew is correct. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29, but at MATH1XX level we do not distinguish an equation and a function.....

Comment: But those are functions defined by their equations, so I don't see why you can say they are functions but not equations?

Comment: An *equation* is an example of a formula.  It has two expressions related by the equal sign.  So $y=(1-x)/(x^2-1)$ is an equation which happens to define a function of $x$.  As is $y=-1/(x+1)$.  John's point is that the two defined *functions* have different domains.  We don't usually talk about the domain of an equation (although a definition does exist).

Comment: @MatthewLeingang oh I think I see your point, it's wrong (or strange) to say an equation has a domain because an equation is a property of a function?

Comment: And although undergraduate math students use terms like *function*, *equation*, *formula*, etc., interchangeably, they are subtly different.  Since one of the goals of undergraduate math is to move from procedures to concepts, processes to objects, I think it's important to distinguish them.

Comment: @Celeritas: exactly.  it's strange to say an equation has a domain because a *domain* is a property of a function.  Also, there's the minor point that there's only *one* equation in the post at this point: $$\frac{1-x}{x^2-1} = -\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Comment: I blame Microsoft Word which invented something called an "Equation Editor" which allows users to insert any mathematical expression or formula.  Somehow or other "equation" became "anything with mathematical symbols in it."

Comment: So if someone said "factor $x^2-1$" the $x^2-1$ would be a formula but not an equation? I remember wondering about that in high school.

Comment: The technical term for $x^2-1$ is *expression*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint:**

$$x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)\\
\frac{1-x}{x^2-1}=\frac{-(x-1)}{(x+1)(x-1)}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{1-x}{x^2-1} = \dfrac{-(x-1)}{(x+1)(x-1)}$ and if $ x \ne 1 $, then $\dfrac{-1}{x+1}$.

With this, $\int\dfrac{1-x}{x^2-1}dx = -\int\dfrac{1}{x+1}=- \ln|x+1|+C$.